# How to group by two Columns using Pandas?

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas

I am working on an algorithm, which requires grouping by two columns. Pandas supports grouping by two columns by using:

```
df.groupby([col1, col2])
```

But the resulting dataframe is not the required dataframe

**Work Setup:**
**Python :** v3.5
**Pandas :** v0.18.1

**Pandas Dataframe - Input Data:**

```
     Type                  Segment
id                              
1   Domestic                 1
2     Salary                 3
3        NRI                 1
4     Salary                 4
5     Salary                 3
6        NRI                 4
7     Salary                 4
8     Salary                 3
9     Salary                 4
10       NRI                 4
```

**Required Dataframe:**
Count of [Domestic, Salary, NRI] in each Segment

```
                  Domestic    Salary    NRI
        Segment
              1          1       3       1
              3          0       0       0
              4          0       3       2
```

**Experiments:**

```
group = df.groupby(['Segment', 'Type'])
group.size()

Segment           Type        Count
1                 Domestic    1
                  NRI         1
3                 Salary      3
4                 Salary      3
                  NRI         2
```

**I am able to achieve the required dataframe using MS Excel Pivot Table feature. Is there any way, where I can achieve similar results using pandas?**

Comment: Did you try - http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After the `Groupby.size` operation, a `multi-index`(2 level index) `series` object gets created that needs to be converted into a dataframe, which could be done by [`unstacking`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) the 2nd level index and optionally filling `NaNs` obtained with 0.

```
df.groupby(['Segment', 'Type']).size().unstack(level=1, fill_value=0)
```

[image]